# How to regularize parameters across a 2D array

Tags: algorithms, regularization, loss-functions, extreme-value

I'm attempting to fit a parameter (which will be a 2D array) to an array of data which corresponds to spatial locations (i.e. longitude/latitude). The parameter can vary from point to point but I want it to vary very smoothly with only small changes between adjacent points (should be spatially stationary to some degree).

So I am planning on minimising

$ \dfrac{1}{2n}\sum_{i,j=-1}^{1} \left( \beta_k - \beta_{i,j} \right)^2 $

for all $k$ where $i,j$ denotes the index of the group of the $n$ nearest array points.

Do I have to minimise each and every $k^{th}$ value in the array or can I combine them into one big objective function?

If the above is a terrible way of going about this, I am happy to receive any suggestions on how I can improve the scheme.

Thanks,

Rachael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is standard practice to combine all the penalities into one big penalty on the objective by summing them.

The penalty you describe costs $O(nN^2)$ complexity to compute, where $N$ is the size of the grid.

A more standard (and computationally efficient) approach to the smoothness constraint you are using here is usually penalizing

$$\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i,j} (\beta_{i,j} - \beta_{i+1,j})^2 + (\beta_{i,j}-\beta_{i,j+1})^2$$

Where $i$ and $j$ range from 1 to N-1.

In other words, we are only applying a direct penalty to horizontally and vertically adjacent entries. In my experience this usually does a pretty good job of what we want it to.